# How to use edsdk.lib file in Android Application?

Tags: android, android-ndk, canon-sdk

I am making an application in which i will need to use edsdk.lib file for implementation of canon sdk integration through Android NDK. i have placed EDSDk.lib file jni folder i have compiled application through Android-ndk.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := sample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sample.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
/*LOCAL_LDLIBS := EDSDK.lib*/
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := EDSDK.lib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

It gived  me following o/p

```
Compile thumb : sample <= sample.c
SharedLibrary  : libsample.so
Install        : libsample.so => libs/armeabi/libsample.so
```

How i compiled EDSDk.lib through Android ndk
plz help

Answer (score 0):

NDK libraries have extension .a, not .lib. "lib" extension comes from Microsoft Visual C++ libraries. If that EDSDK.lib file is not compiled for Android NDK then you won't be able to link it. You must have sources compiled specially for Android to use them with NDK.

Comment: Yes i know this but how can can i use edsdk.lib file in our Androi application how can i change lib file into .a extension file..plz help

Comment: i have changed edsdk.lib file into libedsdk.a file now please suggest to link with Android NDk how to use it in application.?

Comment: You can not rename file and expect it to magically be different format. You must recompile library that genereates edsdk.lib file specially for Android.

Comment: i have used software tool for this i.e http://code.google.com/p/lib2a/downloads/detail?name=LIB2A-2.0.rar for convert edsdk.lib file into edsdk.a file

Comment: You can not take different architecture (x86) and operating system (windows) and automagically convert to arm/android. You must rebuild sources.

Comment: How can i recompile library i.e edsdk.lib to generate edsdk.a for android?plz suggest

Comment: By taking sources and compiling to proper library.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible.
You can't compile a lib file.
Canon has not released an Android version of their SDK.